# I have doubt my hair touched toilet seat upper part

Tags: hadith

I have that my hairs touched toilet seat upper part is my hair najis ?

Comment: If they have feces or urine in them then yes they are unclean and must be washed. But they are not made unclean simply by touching a ceramic or plastic which is clean at that time.